# VS Code не может определить переменные с библиотеки Qt5

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5, gui

[image: Подключенные библиотеки]

VS Code не может определить переменные, однако в университете все работало корректно (IDE в универе PyCharm). Все библиотеки присутствует на ПК.

```
class Main(**QDialog**):
def __init__(self):
    super(Main, self).__init__()
    loadUi('form.ui', self)

    # Задаем заголовок формы
    self.setWindowTitle('Работа с визуальными табличными данными в Python')
    # Задаем логотип формы
    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('images/logo.png'))

    self.BtnRandNum.clicked.connect(self.fill_random_numbers)
    self.BtnSolve.clicked.connect(self.solve)
    self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(**QAbstractItemView**.NoEditTriggers)

def main():
app = **QApplication**(sys.argv)
window = Main()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

участки кода с ошибками пытался взять в жирный шрифт, но к сожелению выделяет только двумя звездочками

Comment: Что в вашем примере обозначают звезды(`**`) в названии классов `**QDialog**`, `**QAbstractItemView**`, `**QApplication**` ?

Comment: Пытался выделить не определенные переменные жирным шрифтом, но сайт выделил двумя звездами.

Comment: я думаю, что вам надо почитать https://habr.com/ru/company/microsoft/blog/450708/